# problems with the current date when modifying a record

Tags: python, django

I need help with my following form:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKpwp.png)

When I'm going to insert the year in the `Año` field (I'm currently working with the `datetimepicker` library which works perfectly) the idea is that the current year appears by default in the `Año` field. I managed to solve this with the following JavaScript code:

```
$('#anno').datetimepicker({    
        format: 'YYYY',
        date: moment().format("YYYY"),
        locale: 'es',
    });
```

The real problem is when I try to modify a record it exists, because the `date: moment().format("YYYY")` property, being active when I am going to modify a record, will have the current year and not the year of the record.

When this property is deactivated, then in the case of inserting, no value appears in the field (but the `datetimepicker` has the current year marked) and in the case of modifying the same thing happens (the `datetimepicker` has the year of the record marked).

I attach the code of my form.py:

```
class OcupacionForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['tipoocupacion'].widget.attrs['autofocus'] = True
           
    class Meta:
        model = OcupacionPortador
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'anno': TextInput(
                attrs={            
                    'autocomplete': 'off',
                    'class': 'form-control datetimepicker-input',
                    'id': 'anno',
                    'data-target': '#anno',
                    'data-toggle': 'datetimepicker'
                }
            ),
            'tipoocupacion': Select(attrs={'class': 'select2', 'style': 'width: 100%'}),
            'mes': Select(attrs={'class': 'select2', 'style': 'width: 100%'}),
            'lectura': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Ingrese una lectura',}),     
        }
```

I need that when I go to insert a record in it, the current year appears by default, but that when I go to update a record, the value that appears is that of the record, not that of the current year.